# adding an object into an object in set of array by loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to add set of object into an object in a set of array by loop. Below is my example, I'm not sure if my explaining even makes sense.

```
var myObject = {x: ["random", "random person"], y: ["tree"]};

var array = [ {
  username: 'example',
  tagline: 'value',
  noises: ['noise', 'sneeze'] 
}, {
  username: 'example1',
  tagline: 'value1',
  noises: ['quack', 'honk', 'sneeze', 'growl'] 
}, {
  username: 'example2',
  tagline: 'value2', 
  noises: ['what', 'up', 'doc']
}, {
  username: 'example3',
  tagline: 'value3',
  noises: ['ptshshhh', 'spit', 'asdfsadf']
}];

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].newObject = myObject;
}
```

When I add the newObject into objects in array, it outputs each object in array as

```
newObject: { x: [Object], y: [Object] } }
```

if I remove the i from array[i], it will only add the

```
var myObject = {x: ["random", "random person"], y: ["tree"]};
```

only at the end. I want it so that, myObject is added into every object in the array as newObject.

Comment: don't use "array" as a variable name. Try something like 'usersArray', or just "users". Just a hint ;)

Comment: @andre If it were a reserved word he would get a syntax error and the code wouldn't run.

Comment: it looks fine to me, are you sure the object's properties are not present?

Comment: @dandavis I misused the words. I've update my comment. Its just a matter of good practices in general programming

Comment: I've tested your code in the Google Chrome's console, and it works just fine

Comment: @andre: what's wrong with using `array` ? i don't see the problem...

Comment: @dandavis array is a reserved word in many programming languages. And this variable name doesn't tell the programmer what it stores at all

Comment: I can't think of any programming languages where `array` is a reserved word. Javascript has a class named `Array`, but that doesn't affect `array` because it's case-sensitive.

Comment: @Barmar PHP is an example

Comment: http://repl.it/uXR/1 I'm running in repl.it it seems the output of array value doesnt print out the object value in myObject. it only prints out: newObject: {x: [Object], y: [Object]}

Comment: @user4852194: that's just how repl formats it, it's fine. view `JSON.stringify(array)` if in doubt

Comment: @user4852194 open your browser console, then paste your code and run it. You'll see that everything is fine

Comment: @dandavis: I just wanted to make sure if my code was correct =) I was just curious why my object property values were not printing when I use for loop. thank you everyone! =)

Comment: @andre: i only worry about the rules of the language i'm programming with. if we have to follow the rules and conventions of other languages too, things get complex... i agree it could be more descriptive, but myObject ain't that great either, and this is just a test demo.

Comment: its just the way dev tool behaves, otherwise the array is updated with new property, so seems to be a question but just a confusion about dev tool output

Comment: @dandavis you'll change your mind when you handle some code which the variables are just generic names like 'array'

Comment: One thing about your code: All the `newObject` properties refer to the **same** object. If you modify one of them, you modify all of them. Assigning objects in Javascript does not make a copy.

Comment: @andre: well i agree 100% that actual projects should use names meaningful to the project. that said, i don't think variable names are something that one should encounter very often in well-written JS anyway; functions/methods abstract away such details to the point that a one-letter var name suffices "deep inside" the guts. consider jQuery for example. i do like Hungarian-notation with formal parameter names though, since you do see those quite a bit when coding and in the console. in that light, arrArray is really dumb...

Comment: Your code works fine. I added this little loop to dump the array. `for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].newObject = myObject;
    console.log('------' + array[i] + '-------- ' + i );
    for (eachProperty in array[i]){
        console.log(eachProperty + ' -> ' + array[i][eachProperty]);
    }

}`

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working, but are you aware that you are copying by reference not value?

When you do this:

```
array[i].newObject = myObject;
```

You ARE NOT making a copy of myObject and assigning it to the property newObject of the object at array[i], you are making a reference to myObject. If you change anything to newObject it will effect all references to it.

If this is what you want fine, if not you will want to make an object literal in place of your reference like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i].newObject = {
        x: ["random", "random person"], 
        y: ["tree"]
    };
}

// changing first x element in newObject of array[0]
array[0].newObject.x[0] = 'not random';

// change only effected array[0]
console.log(array[0].newObject.x[0]); // not random
console.log(array[1].newObject.x[0]); // random
```

Other solutions will involve a constructor function, or the use of some kind of cloning function.

When it comes to viewing the state of your array, you will want to write another function that you might call draw, viewer, or render. You can use console.log() to output to the console, or do something with the DOM if this is client side code.

```
// simple viewer that just logs username, and state of newObject to console.
var viewer = function(profiles){
    var i=0,len = profiles.length;
    while(i < len){
        console.log('**********')
        console.log('username: '+profiles[i].username);
        console.log('newObject: ' + JSON.stringify(profiles[i].newObject));
        i++;
    }
};
```